# Goodness of fit chi-square test for a number of PCA components

Tags: r, pca, chi-squared-test, p-value, factor-analysis

I have been trying to carry out Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in R using the function `psych::principal`. However the returned $p$-value has been very low in several attempts using different sets of variables.

Does it mean that the test of the hypothesis that the number of components is sufficient is rejected?  (The number of components was obtained using the scree plot and the criterion of eigenvalue larger than 1.)

Is it unimportant for the purpose of obtaining components using PCA? If not, what can be done?

```
                       RC1  RC2  RC4  RC3  RC5
SS loadings           5.19 4.24 3.01 2.63 1.16
Proportion Var        0.27 0.22 0.16 0.14 0.06
Cumulative Var        0.27 0.50 0.66 0.79 0.85
Proportion Explained  0.32 0.26 0.19 0.16 0.07
Cumulative Proportion 0.32 0.58 0.77 0.93 1.00

Test of the hypothesis that 5 components are sufficient.

The degrees of freedom for the null model are  171  and the objective function was  23.32
The degrees of freedom for the model are 86  and the objective function was  2.64 
The total number of observations was  103  with MLE Chi Square =  241.11  with prob <  1.2e-16
```

Thank you very much for the answers and input! All help are very much appreciated! I look forward to more detailed documentation of the package to be available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Goodness of fit cannot be meaningfully computed for PCA. The `principal` function is doing something strange here.**

Function `principal()` is part of the `psych` package that implements factor analysis, and is designed to implement PCA in a manner mimicking factor analysis. In factor analysis, goodness of fit can be meaningfully computed as follows.

Given a $p\times p$ covariance matrix $\mathbf S$, factor analysis fits a $p\times k$ matrix of loadings $\mathbf W$ where $k$ is the number of factors and a diagonal $p\times p$ matrix of uniquenesses $\boldsymbol \Psi$ such that $$\mathbf S \approx \mathbf C = \mathbf W \mathbf W^\top + \boldsymbol \Psi.$$ There are different methods of "factor extraction", differing in how exactly the distance between $\mathbf C$ ans $\mathbf S$ is measured. Maximum likelihood method finds loadings and uniquenesses maximizing log-likelihood of the observed data. The log-likelihood of the data is given by $$L_k=-\frac{n}{2}\left[p\ln(2\pi) + \ln|\mathbf C| + \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf C^{-1}\mathbf S)\right],$$ where $n$ is the number of data points (observations). Given two models with different number of factors $k_1$ and $k_2$, they can be compared via a likelihood ratio test that tells us that $$2(L_{k_1} - L_{k_2}) \sim \chi^2_{\mathrm{df}_1-\mathrm{df}_2}.$$ In particular, a model with $k$ factors can be compared to the "full" model with $k=p$ and $\mathbf C=\mathbf S$.

In PCA, there is no $\boldsymbol \Psi$ and so $\mathbf C_\mathrm{PCA}=\mathbf W\mathbf W^\top$. This makes $\mathbf C$ low-rank, with zero determinant, and non-invertible.

**Consequently, in PCA likelihood cannot be computed and likelihood ratio is undefined (ultimately because PCA is not a probabilistic model).**

What exactly `principal()` is doing to "compute" it, is impossible to understand from [its manual page](http://www.personality-project.org/r/psych/help/principal.html). Having looked into its source code I saw that all the goodness of fit computations are done by the `factor.stats()` function, which again has [an unclear manual page](http://www.personality-project.org/r/psych/help/factor.stats.html). The source code of `factor.stats()` reveals that after computing model covariance matrix $\mathbf C = \mathbf W\mathbf W^\top$, the algorithm makes its diagonal equal to the diagonal of $\mathbf S$ (making it full rank). This is the correct computation in factor analysis because there the diagonals of $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf S$ always coincide (due to the matrix of uniquenesses), but makes no sense in PCA.

The resulting goodness of fit computation is essentially a factor analysis computation, but with PCA loadings. This is weird. I am not sure how this could be justified. My advice would be to ignore it and to use some other approach instead.

(Having said that, I guess that a very low $p$-value still *does* indicate that the number of components is "not sufficient": after all, such "diagonal-adjusted" $\widetilde{\mathbf C}$ is closer to $\mathbf S$ than the original $\mathbf C$, so if $\widetilde{\mathbf C}$ does not provide a sufficient fit, then $\mathbf C$ does not either.)

Comment: +1, this is a nice piece of detective work. Hopefully, you'll get more credit than 1 vote for all of this.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). However, I think that GoF statistic for PCA still makes sense. Quoting `principal()` documentation: "For a n x n correlation matrix, the n principal components completely reproduce the correlation matrix. However, if just the first k principal components are extracted, this is the best k dimensional approximation of the matrix." In other words, a side effect of PCA is [information loss](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0429v2.pdf). Therefore, my rationale is that GoF statistic indicates how well the resulting matrix represents the original one.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh, yes the quote is correct, but I don't see how this influences what I wrote. Goodness of fit is computed via likelihood ratio, whereas likelihood is undefined for PCA (ultimately because PCA is not a probabilistic model). Too bad.

Comment: Then could you clarify what does `fit` represent from the `principal()`'s return value (http://personality-project.org/r/html/principal.html)?

Comment: @Aleksandr, I would actually rather somebody else clarified this to me! I can only repeat what I wrote in my answer: it is unclear to me from the manual page you give the link to, so I spent some time reading the source code, and it seems to me that the `fit` is computed with PCA covariance matrix $WW^\top$ after replacing its diagonal with the diagonal of the observed covariance matrix. This is strange: it is not what PCA does.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I'm not skilled in matrix algebra, so I can't offer any mathematical explanation, but, as I said, on a _conceptual_ level, it seems valid to me. PCA produces an **approximation** of the full model, thus, a metric that indicates the **level of fit**, that is _GoF_, seems like making sense and appropriate one.

Comment: @Aleksandr, of course one can devise some metric of "fit", yes. But we are talking about a very specific concept here: chi-squared test for goodness of fit. This test is based on a likelihood ratio, and likelihood is undefined for PCA. I would like to know what scientific literature are `psych` computations based on. They do not seem to give any references.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I understand now. I guess, I need to read more about these concepts (chi-squared test, likelihood ratio, etc.). I will post references, if I find them.

Comment: The only ref. that I've found so far is one in [Chapter 6](http://www.personality-project.org/r/book/Chapter6.pdf) of Revelle's book that is related to PCA and might be used for `principal()`'s implementation is [Anderson (1963)](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177704248). Maybe you will make sense of it. UPDATE: Just found that `principal()`'s return value contains `objective`, which is "value of the function that is minimized by maximum likelihood procedures. This is reported for comparison purposes and as a way to estimate _chi square goodness of fit_" (emphasis mine).

Comment: PCA is ultimately a covariance modeling technique. Whenever you have two models for the covariance matrix, you can take a likelihood ratio between them. This is what `principal` must be doing. But I agree with amoeba that the LR test is expected to fail here because of rank deficiencies. A mystery, in the end. If only R developers had a habit of writing better documentation with [Methods and Formulas](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/mv.pdf) ;)

Comment: @StasK: +1 to your comment, thanks for joining in. When you say that any two models of covariance matrix can be compared with a likelihood ratio, do you refer to what I wrote in my answer (the formula I wrote down for factor analysis likelihood can be applied whatever $\mathbf C$ is, whether it came from factor analysis or not)? Is there any way to salvage this test when $\mathbf C$ is rank deficient? I can see one way: to add a small diagonal term proportional to $\mathbf I$ to "regularize" it. This is essentially what would happen in probabilistic PCA (pPCA), by the way.

Comment: Yes, that's what your answer is doing. But the LR tests also appear in all sorts of multivariate analysis problems, e.g., MANOVA. Since $|{\bf C} + a{\bf I}|$ will basically be the product of non-zero eigenvalues of ${\bf C}$ times $a$ to the power = number of its zero eigenvalues, I don't see regularization as a viable answer to produce the LR. `principal` must be doing something of its own.

Comment: @StasK: Well, I think I know what `principal` is doing: see the third from the bottom paragraph of my answer. It's just that I don't see how it makes sense.

Comment: Oh I see now. Well it shouldn't have been doing that. This is more like principal factor estimation method for EFA than proper PCA. Issue resolved for me.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your comments.  I have removed the pseudo MLE chi square from the print function for principal because it clearly leads to confusion.

I have added the root mean square off diagonal residual because this is probably a more useful estimate of goodness of fit.

I have retained the fit of the model to the off diagonal elements.  As everyone will recognize, PCA is not trying to optimally fit the off diagonals but most users act as if that is what they want.

I continue to report them empirical chi square.  This based upon the size of observed residuals and is not MLE based (nor does it need to be).

I will try to document how the various stats are estimated a bit more clearly in the next release of psych (coming soon).

Comment: +1 and thanks for joining in! Can you comment on how exactly you compute "empirical chi square [...] based [on the] residuals" and perhaps point me to some texts explaining how it can be done? I am only familiar with chi square goodness of fit in the context of likelihood ratio, but I am simply not knowledgeable here.

Comment: Welcome to the site, it's great to have you here. I hope you'll contribute to more threads. That said, this seems to be a response to the other answer & comments & isn't quite an answer on its own. Note that CV isn't a discussion forum, but a strict Q&A site. This could be a great answer though, can you say more about what it means for teh RMS off-diag residual to be a "useful estimate of goodness of fit" for a PCA, eg?

Comment: I also would like to understand the difference between BIC and eBIC or between chi square and the empirically found chi square, and which are better? Thanks!